# gdb can't call function

Tags: c++, gdb

I have some problems with debugging my app - when I try to call parser::extractString(...) from gdb shell it return

> No symbol "extractString" in namespace "parser".

When I execute

> info functions extractString

I have this output

> All functions matching regular expression "extractString":
>
> File /home/dmitriy/Sources/transceiver/parser/json.cpp:
>   std::__cxx11::string
>   parser::extractString[abi:cxx11](rapidjson::GenericValue,
>   parser::MultithreadAllocator> const&);
>
> Non-debugging symbols: 0x0000000000506500 
>   parser::extractString[abi:cxx11](rapidjson::GenericValue,
>   parser::MultithreadAllocator> const&)@plt 0x00007ffff77e3640 
>   parser::extractString[abi:cxx11](rapidjson::GenericValue,
>   parser::MultithreadAllocator> const&)@plt

What is the problem with calling this function? Function extractString defined in static library and called from the application without any problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

gdb does not yet support C++11 ABI tags introduced in gcc 5. See these bugs:

- https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=19436
- https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=18601

The simplest workaround for you is probably to disable new gcc ABI by defining the macro `_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI` to 0, see https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-5/changes.html#libstdcxx.

Or alternatively you can try to apply workarounds from https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=18601#c1 though they look a bit weird.

Comment: Looks like that using `_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI` in my code also require using it for all dependent libraries :-(

Second workarounds don't work - my gdb v7.11 crashed at calling quote-enclosing function name