# gdb conditional break point,cannot find symbol for string global variable?

Tags: c++, string, gdb, global, symbols

I've got a short program:

```
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int i=0;
string s="a";
void f()
{
  ++i;//I wish to break here based on the value of "s"
}
int main()
{
  f();
  s+="b";
  f();
  s+="c";
  f();
  s+="d";
  f();
  return 0;
}
```

I compile and run, break at 'main', enter program, and try to set another point inside "f":

```
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4009c0: file 1.cpp, line 11.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/dev/a.out 

Breakpoint 1, main () at 1.cpp:11
11    f();
(gdb) n
12    s+="b";
(gdb) b 6 if strcmp(s.c_str(),"abc")==0
No symbol "s" in current context.
```

If failed, but as "s" is a global variable, it should be seen by all kinds of context, right?

Why gdb say no symbol "s"?

Comment: I tried on my machine, Ubuntu 14.04 with gcc 4.8.4, I did exactly what you showed but I got no error, the breakpoint was set and it worked, also.
Can you give us more information? gcc version? how do you compile?

Comment: Can you please add the output of `nm -C a.out | grep -w s` to your question? This looks like a possible duplicate of [gdb can't call function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39620026/gdb-cant-call-function). Applying the workaround referenced there, you would type `b 6 if strcmp('s[abi:cxx11]'.c_str(),"abc")==0`, which works for me with gcc5 and gdb 7.11.1.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu1604 with gcc5.4 and compile with g++ -g 1.cpp. Thanks for your answer, this 's[abi:cxx11]' works for me. This seems to be what Mark suggested as gdb doesn't support yet gcc5 feature of cpp 11 support. Anyhow, it's working now.