# GDB No symbol “weird_variable” in current context on unordered_map with struct

Tags: c++, c++11, debugging, gdb, g++

I am running GCC version 6.2 and GDB version 7.12. I am running on Windows 10 using Mingw from MSYS2 with Codeblocks. When I try to run the following test sample, GDB says that the `weird_variable` is not available in this scope.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_set>
using namespace std;
struct PathPair{
    int start = -1;
    int end = -1;
    int time = -1;
};
std::unordered_map<std::string, PathPair> weird_variable;
int main()
{
    PathPair p;
    p.start = 55;
    p.end = 100;
    p.time = 550;
    weird_variable["I"] = p;
    std::cout << weird_variable["I"].end;
    return 0;
}
```

I do have the `-g` option, I've also tried a bunch of others like `-g3`. The exact command that Codeblocks ran was:

```
g++.exe -Wall -fexceptions -g -Wall -std=c++11 -m64 -g -IE:\msys2\mingw64\bin -IE:\msys2\mingw64\lib -c E:\codeblocksworkspace\TEST\main.cpp -o obj\Debug\main.o
g++.exe  -o bin\Debug\TEST.exe obj\Debug\main.o  -m64  
Output file is bin\Debug\TEST.exe with size 706.11 KB
```

However, as I step through the code in the debugger line by line `weird_variable` is still "unavailable". Is there any way I can see it short of printing it every time I want to look at it? Can anyone reproduce this?

Comment: Does `nm -C TEST.exe | grep weird` show the name  `weird_variable[abi:cxx11]` ?

Comment: I put the exe on a linux machine and ran `nm -C TEST.exe | grep weird` and also `nm -C main.o | grep weird` and for both it said `nm: *filename*: File format not recognized` probably because it was built for windows (I think)

Comment: I opened `main.o` it in notepad++ and did CTRL-F "weird" and found `_Z14weird_variableB5cxx11`

Comment: Same with `TEST.exe`. I got `weird_variableB5cxx11`

Comment: OK, this is likely a dup of [gdb can't call function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39620026/gdb-cant-call-function). Workarounds are (a) compile with `-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0` or (b) use the expression `'weird_variable[abi:cxx11]'` (including the quotes) in gdb.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Thanks! That solved my problem